# NSUndoManager registerUndoWithTarget setting wrong value

Tags: macos, cocoa-bindings

In my OS X 10.11 Cocoa application, using Swift 2, I'm trying to implement the undo manager for a bound text field and when I hit undo, it's always just putting 0 for the value, instead of what I stored.  I used the code shown below.  If I add some print() statements in I see the proper values going in to the register statement, but the undo always writes a 0 back.  What have I done wrong?  The NSTextField is bound to the "ud" property.

```swift
private func updatePointValue(key: String, value: Double) {
    let index = key.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
    let first = String(key.characters.first!).uppercaseString
    let rest = key.substringFromIndex(index)
    let selector = Selector("set\(first)\(rest):")

    let oldValue = order.amounts[key]!
    undoManager!.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector: selector, object: oldValue)

    order.amounts[key] = value
}

dynamic var ud: Double {
    get {
        return order.amounts["ud"] ?? 0
    }
    set {
        updatePointValue("ud", value: newValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of `registerUndoWithTarget` is an object. Swift will convert the Double to a NSNumber but the undo manager doesn't convert the NSNumber to a Double.

Comment: Thank you! I pass in a dictionary now with key and value, and then calls a method which invokes updatePointValue with the right items again.